# Error al abrir un archivo excel generado desde c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

estoy creando un archivo excel apartir de un datatable, el problema que tengo es que al momento de abrir el archivo que se genero me
esta abriendo un mensaje "El formato y la extension de archivo no coinciden. Puede que el archivo este dañado o no sea seguro..." alguien sabe
como puedo quitar ese mensaje? yo creo que es por que se esta escribiendo en xml pero no se como escribirlo de forma normal

```html
public void DescargaExcel2(DataTable tabla)
        {
            try
            {
                string nombreArchivo = "Cifra");
                string userFolder = Environment.UserName;
                string pathToSaveFile = "C:\\Users\\" + userFolder + "\\Downloads\\" + nombreArchivo + ".xls";

                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                tabla.WriteXml(pathToSaveFile);
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + pathToSaveFile + "");
                context.Response.WriteFile(pathToSaveFile);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message + "error al generar el xls");
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]